# How do I merge these objects together while retaining the highest amount of detail?

Tags: sculpting, retopology

I'm working on another character model. I've sculpted the hands and feet individually to retain a high amount of detail using a technique in which I crudely construct everything out of spheres, join them into a single object, remesh the object, and touch it up in sculpt mode.

[image: The high-res hand.]

I'm pretty much at the point where I'd like to join the hands and feet with the rest of the body to get rid of the visible seams. However, then I join the hands with the body and remesh the body in sculpt mode, the results get messy:

[image: The hand after remeshing.]

I've attempted to alleviate this with face sets, in hopes that I could direct the retopology to only the grey portion of the sculpt:

[image: The hand, in sculpt mode, with face sets.]

However, the results remained the same.

[image: The fingers, stuck together.]

I've also attempted to merge the hand with the body using a boolean modifier, but this usually just causes the computer to hang.

What's the best way to join these two together?

Comment: at this point, it is good to remember for your future project to not place fingers close to each other because remesh will think that those vertices are supposed to be together... You can make it better with a few settings but I would suggest to you to join the meshes and use Dyntopo instead of remesh on those parts that are needed to be joints

Comment: I'll keep that in mind! I just used a boolean modifier to join the hands with the body, _applied_ the modifier, enabled dyntopo in sculpt mode, and used the simplify and smooth brushes to polish things out. [It worked out great!](https://i.imgur.com/HDZ9IBb.png) Thank you!